# Prove independence using the fact that a joint distribution is multivariate normal?

Tags: probability

We have the random variables $X$ and $Y$, and each is distributed normally according to $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

We wish to show that the sum $(X+Y)$ and the difference $(X-Y)$ are independent by invoking the fact that their distribution is multivariate normal. Reading around a little, I've found that with this distribution, pairwise independence implies independence. How can I go about showing pairwise independence?

I then need to find the variance–covariance matrix for two transformed
variables, $Z=2X+3Y$ and $V=3X-2Y$. I'm not familiar with this process, but I can only find results online for this process using Excel, R, etc. Is there a simple way to do this hand calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several key facts are involved:

- If two normal random variables are independent, then they are jointly follow a multivariate normal with a diagonal covariance matrix. Here I presume $X$ and $Y$ are independent in this context
  So $X, Y$ will jointly follows a multivariate normal
- Any affine transformation of multivariate normal is still multivariate normal. Therefore
  $$ \begin{bmatrix} X + Y \\ X - Y \end{bmatrix}
  = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & - 1\end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}X \\ Y\end{bmatrix}$$
  is just another multivariate normal.
- If two normal random variables jointly follow a multivariate normal, they are independent if and only if they are uncorrelated. So you merely need to show that their covariance is equal to zero, which is easy by linearity: 
  $$ \begin{align*} Cov[X+Y, X-Y] 
  & = Cov[X, X] - Cov[Y, Y] + Cov[Y, X] - Cov[X, Y]\\
  & = Var[X] - Var[Y] + 0 - 0  \\
  & = 0 \end{align*}$$

For the remaining part, you can again use the linearity of covariance to answer the question. Maybe just left that for you to try to find out the covariance of
$Z, V$ first.

Answer (score 0):

If $P(x,y)$ is the joint probability distribution of $x$ and $y$, then the joint distribution of $z(x,y)$ and $w(x,y)$ is given by $$Q(Z,W)=\int\int P(x,y)\delta(z(x,y)-Z)\delta(w(x,y)-W)dxdy$$

Use this to compute the jpd for your variables. Then you can check if they are independent or not, and compute variances, covariances, etc.